# How to create multiple jar with different main in same project, IntelliJ

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea

Im using IntelliJ 12 and I am trying to configure my project to produce a jar file for each of the main methods I have in it.
I have one project with a main method for a server and a different one for the client and I want to produce a jar file which will run each of these accordingly

A different SO question lead me to this: http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/
Which works fine to create a single jar using one main method however when I create multiple artefacts each with the correct settings for each one and click apply, they all point to the same main class.

Comment: are you on maven project?

Comment: No, just a normal intelliJ project. I hink I have found the issue to be that although they have different main classes, the manifest is in the same location for all of them which means its only updated with the last settings I put it. But as far as I am aware the meta-inf needs to be in the src directory, so im not sure how to get around this

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Create two directories (some where in your source tree). One for each JAR to be built. For example:
   [image]
2. Go to the "Artifacts" pane in "Project Structure"
3. Create a new JAR artifact configuration
4. Complete the fields in the "Create Jar from Modules" dialog. For the "Directory for META-INF/MANIFEST.MF field", change the default value to the path of the appropriate directory created in step 1.
   [image]
5. Click OK
6. In the right pane, rename the artifact definition to an appropriate name.
7. Repeat steps 3-6 for the next JAR
   [image]

Idea will create the manifest files. For example:

[image]

However, when it builds the JARs, IDEA will copy the META-INF directory and its content to the root of the JAR so your MANIFEST.MF file will be in the correct location.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.
Didn't realise the meta-inf files didn't have to be in the src folder